# change JSON key to return to API

Tags: python, arrays, json

I read a table from DynamoDB and send as JSON object to an API. I wanted to change the JSON key name `(reg,dreg,stat,num)` to `(a,b,c,d)`

```
import boto3
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='xx-xxxxxxx-1')
    table = dynamodb.Table('_master')

    response = table.scan()
    data =[sanitize(item) for item in response['Items']]

    while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
        data.extend(sanitize(item) for item in response['Items'])


    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        },
        'body': json.dumps(data)
    }

def sanitize(item):
    item['dreg'] = item['dreg'].rstrip('\r\n')

    return item
```

JSON object is :

```
[{"reg": "29-Oct-18", "dreg": "31-Dec-99", "stat": "R", "num": "xob13020"}, {"reg": "29-Oct-18", "dreg": "31-Dec-99", "stat": "R", "num": "oxb03873"}]
```

I wanted to change the JSON key name `(reg,dreg,stat,num)` to `(a,b,c,d)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Comment: you cannot directly change the names of the key in your dict but you can: 1/ create a copy of your object with the right key names or 2/ append new keys to your dict and delete the old ones

Comment: tried json.replace  - got this error : AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: @KlausD. i am unable to figure this out. can you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new dict with the correct key names. E.g.:

`[ { (k+'1') : v for k,v in sanitize(item).items() } for item in response['Items']]`

(but maybe choose a better naming convention..........)

Comment: I didnt actually get your answer here. i am new to python. help to explain with above example

Comment: Edited my question - for better understanding

Comment: `a` to `a1` is understandable from your code. How do i convert `reg` to `a`

Comment: `name_map = {"reg":"a","dereg":"b","stat":"c","num":"d"}
    data =[ { name_map[k] : v for k,v in sanitize(item).items() } for item in response['Items']]`

Answer (score 1):

First load your json to dict

```
>>> jsonobj = '[{"reg": "29-Oct-18", "dreg": "31-Dec-99", "stat": "R", "num": "xob13020"}, {"reg": "29-Oct-18", "dreg": "31-Dec-99", "stat": "R", "num": "oxb03873"}]'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(jsonobj)
[{u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'xob13020', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}, {u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'oxb03873', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}]
>>> listdata = json.loads(jsonobj)
```

then iterate through the list of dictionaries

```
>>> [item for item in listdata]
[{u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'xob13020', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}, {u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'oxb03873', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}]
>>> [{key:value for key,value in item.iteritems()} for item in listdata]
[{u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'xob13020', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}, {u'stat': u'R', u'num': u'oxb03873', u'reg': u'29-Oct-18', u'dreg': u'31-Dec-99'}]
```

with the mapping of keys in a dictionary data structure,

```
>>> key_value_map = {'stat': 'c', 'num': 'd', 'reg': 'a', 'dreg': 'b'}
```

You can change the key value!

```
>>> [{key_value_map[key]:value for key,value in item.iteritems()} for item in listdata]
[{'a': u'29-Oct-18', 'c': u'R', 'b': u'31-Dec-99', 'd': u'xob13020'}, {'a': u'29-Oct-18', 'c': u'R', 'b': u'31-Dec-99', 'd': u'oxb03873'}]
```